# Flip Array part

Tags: java, arrays

i want to flip a Array from 0 to index n, and all flipped Elements should get reversed.

if i Call Flip(A, 2)
my wish result is

```
true, false, true , true, false
```

(the Array part selcted from 0 to 2 backwards , and the value inverted)

```
public class test{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean[] A = { false, true, false, true, false };

    A = Flip(A, 4);

    print(A);
}

public static Boolean[] Flip(Boolean[] A, int n) {
    Boolean[] Atemp = A;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        Atemp[i] = !A[n - i];
    }

    return Atemp;
}

public static void print(Boolean[] A) {
    for (Boolean b : A)
        System.out.println("" + b);

    System.out.println();
}

}
```

but the result i get is

```
true,false,false,true,false
```

is ther an Error in my Code(most likely)
or is there a Java specific Fault involved.

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Change `i <= n` to `i < n` in your loop.

Comment: Thx, but now Flip(A,2)  is still wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. it doesn't only flip the array, but as well reverses it. Guess that's just a mistake in the specification.
2. your code attempts to reverse the array in-place, but isn't implemented incorrectly.
3. your code has `n` as inclusive upper-bound, but the specification states it should be exclusive.

As for point 1: assuming that's really just an issue with the specification, we can simply ignore that point.

Point 3: just change the for-loop from

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

to get the desired behavior.

Point 2:
Here we can take several approaches: actually implement in-place inversion:

```
public static Boolean[] Flip(Boolean[] A, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2.0; i++) {
        boolean tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = !A[n - i - 1];
        A[n - i - 1] = !tmp;
    }

    return A;
}
```

Or create a copy of the array and invert inside that copy:

```
public static Boolean[] Flip(Boolean[] A, int n) {
    Boolean[] Atemp = Arrays.copyOf(A , A.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Atemp[i] = !A[n - i - 1];
    }

    return Atemp;
}
```

And there's no need to use `Boolean[]`. Just use the primitive type `boolean[]`.

A hint for the future: this can actually be debugged either using a debugger, or if you prefer by simply altering the code to reverse a `int[]` instead of a `boolean[]`. Just use `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...}` it becomes pretty obvious what happens to the single elements.

Comment: thx, the methode should reverse the order of the selected range from 0 to n and then reverse the value of each index, from 0 to n.
If this makes sense.
Sry its late and im not the best english writer

Comment: @Doren in that case you should update the question to match the requirements of the code. Anyways, my code does exactly that. I just took point 1 (incorrect specification) for granted

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use a `boolean[]` (no need for `Boolean[]`). Second, when you assign the reference from `A` to `Atemp` you aren't copying the array (you pass the value of the reference to the function). You need to iterate from `0 < n` and flip the array at each index (not against an offset). Finally, Java naming conventions would use `flip` (because `Flip` looks like a class name).

```
public static void flip(boolean[] arr, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = !arr[i];
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] arr = { false, true, false, true, false };
    flip(arr, 4);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

And I get (as requested)

```
[true, false, true, false, false]
```